# $E[X \mid Y]$ where $Y(x)=x(1-x)$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let's consider $\Omega = [0,1]$ and Lebesgue measure. Also define $Y(x)=x(1-x)$. I want to prove that $$E[X\mid Y](x)=\frac{X(x)+X(1-x)}{2}$$

My first shot was to use $E[X\mid Y]=\frac{E[X1_Y]}{P(Y)}$ but I thought that it's not a good idea, because I cannot say anything about $P(Y)$ since $Y$ distribution is not known.Can you give me a hint how can I start proving this theorem ? I found it not so trivial due to generic form of variables (no distributions).

Comment: The conditional probability formula you wrote down won't work here since $P(Y)$ will equal $0$. What definition of conditional probability are you using?

Comment: Yea I know it won't, was not a good start. I think I'm using the standard one $P(A \mid B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

Comment: That's indeed standard for when $P(B)\ne0$, but a more subtle formula is needed for cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of conditional expectation $\mathbb E[X|Y]$ is such a random variable $Z$ that is $\sigma(Y) := \{Y^{-1}[B] ; B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}$ measurable and for any $D \in \sigma(Y)$ we have $\mathbb E[Z1_D] = \mathbb E[X1_D]$, where $$1_D(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in D \\ 0 & x \not \in D \end{cases}$$

Note that for any $B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ we get $Y^{-1}[B] = \{ x \in [0,1] : Y(x) \in B \} = \{ x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}] : Y(x) \in B \} \cup \{ x \in [\frac{1}{2},1] : Y(x) \in B\} $

But since for every $x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ we have $Y(x) = Y(1-x)$, then such preimage is in form $A \cup (1-A)$, where $1-A := \{1-x \in [0,1] : x \in A \}$ and $A \subset [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ (and clearly we can get any $A \subset [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ measurable)

Note that function $Z(x)= \frac{X(x) + X(1-x)}{2}$ is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable, since $Z(x)= Z(1-x)$, (proceed analogously as above) such preimages $Z^{-1}[B]$ would be of form $C \cup (1-C)$, too, so in $\sigma(Y)$.

This establishes that $Z$ is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable. Now, we need to take any $D \in \sigma(Y)$. We know it is of form $A \cup (1-A)$ for some $A \subset [0,\frac{1}{2}]$. Hence:

$$ \mathbb E[Z1_D]  = \frac{1}{2}\Big(\int_{A} X(x)+X(1-x) dx + \int_{1-A} X(x) + X(1-x)dx\Big) = $$ $$= \frac{1}{2}\Big(\int_{A \cup (1-A)} X(x)dx + \int_{A \cup (1-A)} X(1-x)dx \Big)  $$

Now use substitution $y=1-x$ (note that under such transformation, set $D=A \cup (1-A)$ which is symetricc at $\frac{1}{2}$ would remain unchanged), you'll get:

$$ \mathbb E[Z1_D] = \frac{1}{2} \Big( \int_D X(x) dx + \int_D X(y)dy  \Big) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\int_D X(x)dx = \int_D X(x)dx = \mathbb E[X1_D]$$

Comment: Could you please write down definition of set $A$ ? I can't find it in your solution (Only $1-A$ which is using definition of $A$)

Comment: Firstly when I started to write what is $Y^{-1}[B]$, $A$ is just given by $A:= \{x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}] : Y(x) \in B\}$. It was just to show how sets in $\sigma(Y)$ looks like (that they're in symetric form $A \cup (1-A)$ for SOME $A \subset [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ (we don't really bother what is $A$ exactly, we only needed that symetry of sets in $\sigma(Y)$). Then any $D \in \sigma(Y)$ has some $A \subset [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ such that $D = A \cup (1-A)$. And latter there are only some calculations based on symetry.

Comment: When you ask a question you should accept the answers you get, otherwise the questions will always stay open.